# solving equation also involving unknown matrix in trace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace

Given two real $m$ x $k$ matrices $A_1$ and $B_1$ and two $k$ x $k$ real matrices $A_2$ and $B_2$ I want to solve the following equation for $Q$. $Q$ is an orthogonal matrix, i.e. $Q^TQ=I$.

$$\frac{tr(Q^TA_1^TB_1)}{tr(A_1^TA_1)} Q^TA_1^TB_1 + Q^TA_2^TB_2 = symmetric$$

The solution to a similar problem (without the trace expression) has e.g. been described by Schönemann (1966, p. 2) and goes like this.

$$ 
Q^TA_1^TB_1 + Q^TA_2^TB_2 = symmetric \\
Q^T(\underbrace{A_1^TB_1 + A_2^TB_2}_{C}) = symmetric \\
Q^TC = C^TQ \\
C = QC^TQ \\
CC^T = QC^TQQ^TCQ^T = QC^TCQ^T
$$

With $CC^T$ and $C^TC$ being diagonizable and having the same latent roots, let

$$ CC^T = WDW^T \text{and} C^TC = VDV^T \\
\text{with} \\
I = W^TW = WW^T = V^TV = VV^T$$

We get
$$ WDW^T = QVDV^TQ^T$$
and thus
$$W=QV \\
\text{and} \\ 
Q=WV^T$$

I tried work out an argument along the same lines but do not know how to do that with the trace expression which also contains $Q$. Any ideas?

PS. I am a psychologist, no mathematician, so please bear with me ;)

Schönemann, P. H. (1966). A generalized solution of the orthogonal procrustes problem. *Psychometrika*, *31*(1), 1–10. doi:10.1007/BF02289451

Comment: your expression is of the form $tr(\cdot)Q^T C$, which obviously is symmetric iff $Q^TC$ is symmetric, therefore, you already know the solution.

Comment: I think we do not know if $Q^TC$ is symmetric. We only know that the sum of the two parts is symmetric, which is IMO not the same.

Comment: To clarify: with $Q^TC$ I mean the upper problem, i.e. $Q^TA_1^TB_1$

Comment: My apologies, your expression is not of the form I wrote in my first comment and the solution is, of course, not the same (unfortunately, I do not know the solution!)

Comment: I am impressed that a psychologist knows so well linear algebra.

Comment: Firstly, you can redefine $\tilde A_1 = A_1/\sqrt{tr(A_1^T A_1)}$. Then your problem will look simpler 
$$
tr(Q^TC_1) (Q^T C_1 -C_1^T Q) +Q^T C_2 - C_2^T Q=0
$$ where $C_1=\tilde A_1^TB_1$, $C_2=A_2^TB_2$

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see here is that it was derived from another model. This equation is from a minimization using least squares. If you can provide the original model, maybe we could derive the second expression needed to solve the constant.

Here is a nice document describing this:

http://www2.isikun.edu.tr/personel/akca/devrim/2003CH_Praktikum_Procrustes.pdf

More information regarding where did you got this problem could be useful.